# Clear the conversation window

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a bot deployed to MS Teams, the problem is everytime i open the bot, i see all my previous conversation history and there is no way for me to clear that conversation and start from fresh. I have implemented Cancel/Quit dialog which will help reset the conversation however that will not remove the previous history, i am looking at ways to clear the screen ( Just like Start Over in the Emulator). I am currently using inmemory storage and not any custom DB.

Appreciate any leads here!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the conversation windows in Microsoft Teams [isn't supported yet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delete-a-chat-in-teams-da6d87ed-59bc-4407-9291-95ee193f8344). It isn't related to your bot storage / code, the conversation data is persisted within your Microsoft Teams tenant.